# OneToOne with Composite Key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Trying to create a one to one on a table with a composite key.
I'm unable to get it to work and getting this error:

Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext-dao.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: broken column mapping for: compensation.id of: com.ciwise.model.Focus

**Compensation.java:**

```
package com.ciwise.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EmbeddedId;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "commissions")
public class Compensation  implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Composite key
 */
private CompensationPK compensationPK;

/**
 * This year monthly net sales
 */
private double tYMonthlyNetSales;

/**
 * Last year monthly net sales
 */

private double lYMonthlyNetSales;

/**
 * This year YTD net sales
 */
private double tYYTDNetSales;

private Focus focus;

/**
 * Getters and Setters
 */

@OneToOne( mappedBy = "compensation", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "FOCUS_ID")
public Focus getFocus() {
    return focus;
}

public void setFocus(Focus focus) {
    this.focus = focus;
}

@EmbeddedId
public CompensationPK getCompensationPK() {
    return compensationPK;
}

public void setCompensationPK(CompensationPK compensationPK) {
    this.compensationPK = compensationPK;
}

@Column(name = "TY_MONTHLY_NET_SALES")
public double gettYMonthlyNetSales() {
    return tYMonthlyNetSales;
}

public void settYMonthlyNetSales(double tYMonthlyNetSales) {
    this.tYMonthlyNetSales = tYMonthlyNetSales;
}

@Column(name = "LY_MONTHLY_NET_SALES")
public double getlYMonthlyNetSales() {
    return lYMonthlyNetSales;
}

public void setlYMonthlyNetSales(double lYMonthlyNetSales) {
    this.lYMonthlyNetSales = lYMonthlyNetSales;
}

@Column(name = "TY_YTD_NET_SALES")
public double gettYYTDNetSales() {
    return tYYTDNetSales;
}

public void settYYTDNetSales(double tYYTDNetSales) {
    this.tYYTDNetSales = tYYTDNetSales;
}
}
```

**CompensationPK.java**

```
package com.ciwise.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class CompensationPK implements Serializable {

private String divisionId;

private String repId;

private int focusId;

private int repTypeId;

private int commissionYear;

private int commissionMonth;

@Column(name = "DIVISION_ID")
public String getDivisionId() {
    return divisionId;
}

@Column(name = "REP_ID")
public String getRepId() {
    return repId;
}

@Column(name = "FOCUS_ID")
public int getFocusId() {
    return focusId;
}

@Column(name = "REPTYPE_ID")
public int getRepTypeId() {
    return repTypeId;
}

@Column(name = "COMMISSION_YEAR")
public int getCommissionYear() {
    return commissionYear;
}

@Column(name = "COMMISSION_MONTH")
public int getCommissionMonth() {
    return commissionMonth;
}



public void setDivisionId(String divisionId) {
    this.divisionId = divisionId;
}

public void setRepId(String repId) {
    this.repId = repId;
}

public void setFocusId(int focusId) {
    this.focusId = focusId;
}

public void setRepTypeId(int repTypeId) {
    this.repTypeId = repTypeId;
}

public void setCommissionYear(int commissionYear) {
    this.commissionYear = commissionYear;
}

public void setCommissionMonth(int commissionMonth) {
    this.commissionMonth = commissionMonth;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
}
```

**Focus.java:**

package com.ciwise.model;

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "CT_FOCUS")
public class Focus implements Serializable {

private int focusId;
private String focusDesc;
private String focusYN;
private Compensation compensation;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Compensation getCompensation() {
    return compensation;
}

public void setCompensation(Compensation compensation) {
    this.compensation = compensation;
}

public Focus() {
};

@Id
@Column(name = "FOCUS_ID")
public int getFocusId() {
    return focusId;
}

public void setFocusId(int focusId) {
    this.focusId = focusId;
}

@Column(name = "FOCUS_DESC", length = 16)
public String getFocusDesc() {
    return focusDesc;
}

public void setFocusDesc(String focusDesc) {
    this.focusDesc = focusDesc;
}

@Column(name = "FOCUS_YN", length = 1)
public String getFocusYN() {
    return focusYN;
}

public void setFocusYN(String focusYN) {
    this.focusYN = focusYN;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used an embeddable type (`CompositionPK`) as your primary key for `Composition` entity, you should annotate the corresponding primary key field in your `Composition` entity with `@EmbeddedId`.

```
@EmbeddedId
private CompensationPK compensationPK;
```

On the `Focus` entity, you need not specify a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` on the one-to-one mapping. It will just use the default join column names for the foreign keys.

So this code should be fine without the `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`:

```
@OneToOne
public Compensation getCompensation() {
    return compensation;
}
```

This is a sample Hibernate generated schema based on your mappings (target DB is MySQL):

```
Hibernate: 
    create table CT_FOCUS (
        FOCUS_ID integer not null,
        FOCUS_DESC varchar(16),
        FOCUS_YN varchar(1),
        compensation_COMMISSION_MONTH integer,
        compensation_COMMISSION_YEAR integer,
        compensation_DIVISION_ID varchar(255),
        compensation_FOCUS_ID integer,
        compensation_REP_ID varchar(255),
        compensation_REPTYPE_ID integer,
        primary key (FOCUS_ID)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table commissions (
        COMMISSION_MONTH integer not null,
        COMMISSION_YEAR integer not null,
        DIVISION_ID varchar(255) not null,
        FOCUS_ID integer not null,
        REP_ID varchar(255) not null,
        REPTYPE_ID integer not null,
        LY_MONTHLY_NET_SALES double precision,
        TY_MONTHLY_NET_SALES double precision,
        TY_YTD_NET_SALES double precision,
        primary key (COMMISSION_MONTH, COMMISSION_YEAR, DIVISION_ID, FOCUS_ID, REP_ID, REPTYPE_ID)
    )
Hibernate: 
    alter table CT_FOCUS 
        add constraint FK_d6d2c9n91dlw59uiuqswfueg5 
        foreign key (compensation_COMMISSION_MONTH, compensation_COMMISSION_YEAR, compensation_DIVISION_ID, compensation_FOCUS_ID, compensation_REP_ID, compensation_REPTYPE_ID) 
        references commissions (COMMISSION_MONTH, COMMISSION_YEAR, DIVISION_ID, FOCUS_ID, REP_ID, REPTYPE_ID)
```

`@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` can be used on a `@OneToOne` mapping, if you want the primary keys of `Focus` entity to be referencing the primary keys of `Commission` entity. However, you already have defined a primary key for your `Focus` entity, which the `focusId` annotated by `@Id`. So there's no need to specify a `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

Comment: Got this error when trying to run the code: WARN - SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(145) | SQL Error: -205,    SQLState: 42703
ERROR - SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(147) | [SQL0205] Column COMMISSION_REPTYPE_ID not in table CT_FOCUS in CUSDBDV.

Comment: are you using schema auto-generation properties in your config (i.e. hbm2ddl.auto)? If so, set it to either create or update, to update your schema. Your error indicates, that the foreign key column cannot be located in your CT_FOCUS table.